# Can I upgrade RAM on late 2013 retina Mac Book Pro?

Tags: upgrade, macbook-pro, memory

Do the late 2013 models (13" - (ME864, ME865, ME866), 15" - (ME293, ME294)) support RAM upgrades?

Answer (score 24):

No. The RAM is soldered to the logic board in all of these models.

[image]

Here is the logic board from [iFixit's Teardown](https://www.ifixit.com/Teardown/MacBook+Pro+15-Inch+Retina+Display+Late+2013+Teardown/18696) of the low end 15'' model (2.0 GHz, 8 GB RAM, 256 SSD).

Inside the yellow box are 16 x 512 MB DDR3 SDRAM (8 GB total) memory chips. As you can see, they are soldered directly to the board and cannot be replaced without replacing the whole logicboard.

Comment: You could therefore have the logic board upgraded :p

Comment: One could upgrade to 32Gb now IF: the question remains in my mind what would happen if one replaces 512Mb modules with 2Gb ones. Are ones from modern SODIMM compatible by matrix of solder balls (BGAs)? Would motherboard accept the replacement?

Answer (score 6):

Per [the teardown performed by iFixit](https://www.ifixit.com/Teardown/MacBook+Pro+13-Inch+Retina+Display+Late+2013+Teardown/18695), the RAM in Retina Displays is soldered to the logic board. It may be possible to undo the soldering and upgrade it, but the hassle is almost surely not worth it.

https://www.ifixit.com/Teardown/MacBook+Pro+13-Inch+Retina+Display+Late+2013+Teardown/18695#s53264

[image: RAM soldered to logic board]

Comment: Board's facing the wrong way. [This is the image you want](https://d3nevzfk7ii3be.cloudfront.net/igi/AG3pwEJMI5xJ6Vcd.huge) :)